# Magento 2 Missing required argument $areaCode of Magento\Framework\App\Area

Tags: cli, magento2.2.7

I'm using CLI to execute a custom module, that generate a custom sales report.

It has been working nicely, but it suddenly failed with the error `Missing required argument $areaCode of Magento\Framework\App\Area` for those orders that has status 'closed'.

I have in the `execute`function set areacode since very beginning. I'm not sure why all of sudden it gives error.

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
    $task = trim($input->getOption(self::TASK_OPTION));
    if(!empty($task)) {
        return $this->processTask($task);
    }

    $this->cronProcessReports->process();
}
```

how can I fix this?

I'm using Magento2.2.7

Comment: Have you tried to set the area code?
In your execute() method put this line at the beginning:

```$this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);```

$this->state is **\Magento\Framework\App\State** that you have to instantiate in your constructor.

Comment: @MattiaKozianowski yes I did set the areacode. I have also updated the question with execute() function

Comment: Can you attach the constructor?

Comment: @MattiaKozianowski Thanks for the help so far. The problem is solved. It was another custom module that also use app/area, and that module wasn't compile well, thus giving error.